# How can i create concern method with different Class names (depending on Controller)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have 2 controllers. Both are very similar, the difference is only the Model Class name.

For example:

production_controller.rb

```
  def new_task_order_counter(board_id)
    tasks = Production.where(board_id: board_id)
    task_order = tasks.count + 1
  end
```

development_controller.rb

```
  def new_task_order_counter(board_id)
    tasks = Development.where(board_id: board_id)
    task_order = tasks.count + 1
  end
```

I want to create a concern where there will be one method replacing both of these methods in my controllers. Is there way to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concern is the way to go

Create one in `app/controllers/concerns`:

```
module TasksConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def new_task_order_counter(scope, board_id)
      tasks = scope.where(board_id: board_id)
      task_order = tasks.count + 1

      # you could simplify to:
      # scope.where(board_id: board_id).count + 1 
    end
  end
end
```

To use it in your controller add this line:

```
include TasksConcern
```

And use the method like that:

```
order = new_task_order_counter(Development, board_id)
```